# How to add business logic to generated entities in entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework-6

In previous versions of EF, the use of partial classes extending entities with business logic is well documented.  However in EF6, T4 templates are used to generate the entities in separate files for each class (each filename matching it's class name).  This leaves no place for partial classes as they would have the same filenames.

So how do we extend the classes to add methods and meta annotations?

Comment: It is preferable to include what you have done - ie that shows that you are trying and you need help rather than that you just want someone to give you the work predone. From how you've phrased your question I don't think that's the case but unfortunately I'm not familiar with entity Framework to give you pointers.

Comment: To solve the problem, I renamed the filenames of all partial classes by appending "Partial".   Inside the file, I kept the class name the same.   The results is legacy compatible too.